# Fuzzy matching inside a column

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy, fuzzywuzzy

Suppose I have a list of sports like this :

```
sports=["futball","fitbal","football","tennis","tenis","tenisse","footbal","zennis","ping-pong"]
```

I would like to create a dataframe that match each element of sport with it's closest if the fuzzy matching is superior than 0.5 and if it's not just match it with itself. (I want to use the function fuzzywuzzy.fuzz.ratio(x,y) for that)

The result should look like :

```
pd.DataFrame({"sport":sports,"closest_match":["futball","futball","football","tennis","tennis","tennis","futball","tennis","ping-pong"]})

    sport   closest_match
0   futball futball
1   fitbal  futball
2   football football
3   tennis  tennis
4   tenis   tennis
5   tenisse tennis
6   footbal futball
7   zennis  tennis
8   ping-pong ping-pong
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution using [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd
sports = ["futball", "fitbal", "football", "tennis", "tenis", "tenisse", "footbal", "zennis", "ping-pong"]
dist = ([x for x in itertools.combinations(sports, 2) if fuzz.ratio(*x) > 50])

df = pd.DataFrame(dist, columns=["sport","closest"])
df['ratio'] = dist = ([fuzz.ratio(*x) for x in itertools.combinations(sports, 2) if fuzz.ratio(*x) > 50])
print(df)

df = df.groupby(['sport'])[['closest','ratio']].agg('max').reset_index()
```

output:

```
      sport   closest  ratio
0    fitbal  football     77
1  football   footbal     93
2   futball  football     80
3     tenis    zennis     83
4   tenisse    zennis     62
5    tennis    zennis     91
```

Comment: Thanks ! however I would like to have only one modality, it looks like a clustering task...

Comment: what do you mean by only one modality?

Comment: 1 modality for football for example, 1 for tennis, 1 for ping pong. Here there are zennis, tenisse, tenis etc

Comment: the best score?

Comment: mmmh yes I think it's a good idea so it reduces the number of modalities

Comment: so impossible without  reference words to eliminate this word or this word

Comment: i have added a groupby with agg max, its the best solution